# 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer - from python2.X to python3.8

Tags: python

Currently the following error occurs. I believe the problem is due to this code been written for python 2.X and not working in my current version of python 3.8.3

`self.zz=np.zeros(self.nhalf,'f') TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

References to `self.zz` and `self.nhalf` in the program are shown below

```
self.nhalf=0
self.nhalf=self.num_fft/2

self.zz=[]
self.zz=self.zz[n1:n2]
```

I wonder is there simple adjustment required to remove the error?

Comment: From [`numpy` docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html#numpy-zeros): *`numpy.zeros(shape, dtype=float, order='C')` shape : __int__ or __tuple of ints__* -- `/` returns a float...

Comment: Since Python 3.5(I think) the `/` operator does regular division, meaning the result could be a float. If you want floor division, you can use the `//` operator.

Comment: @jaaq correction: *meaning the result __is always__ a float*

Comment: @Tomerikoo oh you're right! I never bothered to try `type(4/2)`. Thanks, learned something new :)

Comment: @jaaq No need. The result of `4/2` is `2.0` which gives a hint of its type ^_^

Comment: hahaha, yeay, fair xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the problem is that Python2 did integer division by default while Python3.5(ish) started using regular division.

I think your error means that you are trying to create a numpy array with e.g. 17.5 zeros in it, which obviously doesn't work.

Try replacing the `/` operator with the `//` floor division operator:

```
self.nhalf=self.num_fft//2
```